# How to Embed an Apex website on my HTML Website

Tags: html, iframe, embed, apex

I have an Apex application which I use for CMS of my website, I want to embed this on my website when a user logs in.

I have tried using an iframe however the APEX Application does not show in the iframe.

What is the correct way for embedding an APEX Application inside an HTML website?

Comment: Done now, needed to allow embedding on the APEX Application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the APEX Application manager there is a setting to allow browser embedding this must be enabled in order to embed in an iframe. I had overlooked this setting when trying it.

Answer (score 0):

As a new user of APEX it was not clear exactly where to find the setting mentioned by the OP. For **APEX 5** I found the setting to enable iframes as follows:

1. Open APEX in your browser (for example, my URL is `http://some-host:1337/ords`)
2. Login to your workspace as an administrator
3. Click on **Application Builder**
4. Click the name of the application you want to enable to open it
5. On the title bar where your application name appears, click on **Edit Application Properties** (button to the right)
6. Toward the top, locate the link for **Security** and click it
7. Scroll down to the **Browser Security** section or click on the tab labeled Browser Security
8. Assuming it says *Deny*, change it to **Allow** or **Allow from same origin**
9. Press **Apply Changes**

Once this is complete you should be able to embed a URL for that specific APEX application in the `src="[apex_url]"` attribute of an iframe.

> **Note:** Choosing **Allow** vs **Allow from same origin** depends on whether or not your application is running on the same host / root URL. In my case, the iframe was served from a different URL thus I chose **Allow**. Out of scope for this question but, for security reasons, you probably need to consider the implications of allowing this in your own environment.